GCP client library method to download Object
I came across two ways to read the Objects from GCS buckets.
storage.readAllBytes
An article (below) suggests use of "storage.readAllBytes"
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects-into-memory#code-samples-download-object-into-memory
The documentation says, this method is fast way to download entire object in memory, so I am assuming this makes one GET call to Google Cloud to download entire Object.
storage.get(blobId); blob.getContent()
This article suggest use of storage object to get the Blob first, and another request to get the Content.
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
String value = new String(blob.getContent());
I assume, above way of reading the data makes 2 HTTP GET calls to Google Cloud to download read Object.
I have a use case where my XML documents are 5-10 MB in size and I need to download them based on the Object id to perform some transformation in my Java application. I am trying to find fastest way to read the document in my Java application.
Wanted to ask, which of the above methods should be used for faster download time.

readAllBytes is the fastest one. I don't know why you ask the question about get blod id function.

As per this document Download an object into memory it is recommended to use readAllBytes. Also, can you share the second document which you are referring to.
